# I'm facing a runtime custom error problem on server

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I'm facing a custom error problem on server.can u plz help me out

Runtime Error

```
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.
```

this custom error appears only on those pages on them i used java script programing in images and for some other purpose. plz hepl me out....

Comment: That is an error on the *server*. Unless you have a very odd setup, your Javascript runs on the *client*. These are different domains. Either the error is nothing to do with what you are doing, or (more likely) your javascript is issuing a request that the server doesn't like. You need to find out what request your client session is issuing. You could also usefully consider how you expect anybody to help you when you have told us nothing about what you are using: for example what browser, what server program, do you have control of the server, etc.

Comment: You've turned off customErrors and still you're seeing this page? I guess there is something wrong at your server. Javascript has got nothing to do with it as it's a client-side scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

If you temporarily add the xml shown to your web.config then you will see the actual exception causing the problem which will help you identify and fix it. If you view the page from the web server machine locally you should also be able to see the specific exception without turning custom error mode off.